Equation of state: Ideal gas example for energy, entropy, temperature
I'm trying to apply the definition of temperature $$\frac{\partial{U}}{ \partial{S}} \equiv T$$  to a simple example:  an ideal gas expanding adiabatically in a piston. The internal energy is decreasing, because the piston is moving outwards and the KE drops during piston collisions and the entropy is increasing.  Is there a sign problem?  T should be negative by this definition.
Edit: I realized that the partial derivative requires that the other variables (V,N) must be fixed. I'm not just changing S, I'm changing V in my example.
Is there a simple ideal gas example of this equation?

The definition is for a closed constant volume system. If it’s adiabatic the there’s no expansion work and no heat and therefore no change in internal energy or entropy

In the future, please try not to edit questions in ways which invalidate existing answers. If an answer says "approach this problem in some other way," and you see why but have a question about the other way, then "accept" the helpful answer and ask a follow-up question about your new situation.

State variables and partial derivatives in thermodynamics. In order to use partial derivatives, you

first need the expression of a state variable as a function of other two state variables;
then evaluate the partial derivatives you like, keeping in mind the constant independent variable.

!!!Working with multi-variable functions, and with change of variables is 90% of algebra and calculus needed to derive foundations of all the classical thermodynamics!!! (this hint will never be BOLD ENOUGH)
As an example, using the first principle of thermodynamics with $U(V,S)$ or $S(V,U)$
$$dU = - P dV + T dS \qquad \text{or} \qquad dS = \frac{1}{T} dU + \frac{P}{T} dV$$
where the following holds,
$$T = \left( \frac{\partial U}{\partial S} \right)_V \qquad , \qquad \frac{1}{T} = \left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial U}\right)_V$$
$$P = -\left( \frac{\partial U}{\partial V} \right)_S \qquad , \qquad \frac{P}{T} = \left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial V}\right)_U$$
being $dU(V,S)$ and $dS(V,U)$ perfect differentials, or differentials of state functions.
Temperature as partial derivative, for a perfect gas. Thus, in your example using perfect gases - independently from the transformation you're performing -, you first need to write internal energy as a function of $T$ and $S$ and then evaluate the partial derivative. Equation of state and internal energy for a perfect gas read,
$$P V = n R T \qquad , \qquad U = C_V T \ ,$$
while it's possible to write change in entropy as
$$\begin{aligned}
S - S_0 & = C_V \ln\left( \frac{T}{T_0} \right) + n R \ln\left( \frac{V}{V_0} \right) = \\
& = C_V \ln\left( \frac{U}{U_0} \right) + n R \ln\left( \frac{V}{V_0} \right) \ .
\end{aligned}$$
Now that you have an expression of the entropy as a function of internal energy and volume, $S(U,V)$, you can perform the partial derivative remembering that $\frac{d}{dx} \ln \left( \frac{x}{x_0} \right) = \frac{1}{x}$, to get
$$\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial U}\right)_V = \frac{C_V}{U} = \frac{1}{T} \ ,$$
i.e. the desired result. This result is independent from the transformation, as you would expect being "a definition of temperature".
Your example. In an adiabatic expansion, without dissipation, $S$ is constant. In order to describe the state of the system during the thermodynamic transformation, you need the value of another thermodynamic state variable, $X$ (pressure, temperature,... you're free to choose). Anyway you can't expect to get any useful result from differentiation of the function $U(X,S)$, since $V$ is varying (and this contradicts the definition of temperature) and $S$ is constant,
$$T \neq \left( \frac{\partial S}{\partial U} \right)_x = 0 \qquad \text{for every $X$}$$
A working example. In order to use the definition of $T$ having all the required physical quantities and thermodynamic transformation, you need a system that performs a transformation at constant volume: as an example, you can provide heat flux to a gas in a constant volume rigid box.
In this case, $V$ is const, and $dU(\overline{V},S) = T(S) dS$. For constant volume, energy can be written a single variable function of $S$, whose derivative w.r.t. $S$ (at constant $V$) is the temperature.

Yes, there is a simple ideal-gas example of $\left(\frac{\partial U}{\partial S}\right)_{V,N}=T$: heating it. From the First Law, if the volume remains constant, the energy change $\partial U$ corresponds to infinitesimal heating $\delta Q$, and we find that the corresponding entropy change is $dS=\frac{\delta Q}{T}$.
This leads to many useful conclusions. One is that the heating can’t be occurring spontaneously from an adjacent cooler ideal gas at temperature $T^\prime<T$, as that gas would be losing more entropy than the first gas gains, and total entropy destruction is prohibited by the Second Law.
